# Openpyxl Merge cells with same value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, merge, openpyxl

I have write the dataframe below to an excel file

```
df = {'name':  ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e'],
        'type': ['tiger', 'caterpillar', 'butterfly', 'butterfly', 'dolphin', 'tadpole', 'frog', 'dog'],
        'month1_weight': ['33', '0', '0', '0', '59', '3', '0', '0'],
        'month2_weight': ['0', '0', '20', '20', '65', '0', '10', '2'],
        }
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df)

name      type         month1_weight  month2_weight
a         tiger        33             0
b         caterpillar  0              0
b         butterfly    0              20
b         butterfly    0              20
c         dolphin      59             65
d         tadpole      3              0
d         frog         0              10
e         dog          0              2
```

[image]

How can I merge the cells in the name column in Excel and make it be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add the multilevel index to your dataframe using `set_index(["name", "type"])` then using the [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) object you can write the required dataframe to the excel sheet. Use:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df).set_index(["name", "type"])    
with ExcelWriter("excel_file.xlsx") as writer:
    dataframe.to_excel(writer)
```

After executing the above code the contents of your `excel_file` should look like:

[image]

---

EDIT (See comments):

Replace:

```
for col_num, value in enumerate(dataframe.columns.values): 
    worksheet_O.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
```

with:

```
for col_num, value in enumerate(dataframe.reset_index().columns): 
    worksheet_O.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
```

Comment: I don't know why but I did that and the header- type will be replace by month_weight and the number of whole column(month_1 weight) disappear.

Comment: Can you add the picture, showing hows your sheet look like after executing the above code?

Comment: What's old_df in your question?

Comment: ```writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excelfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Overview')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet_O = writer.sheets['Overview']

header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'text_wrap': True, 'valign': 'top', 'border': 1})

for col_num, value in enumerate(dataframe.columns.values):
    worksheet_O.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)

writer.save()
writer.close()```

Comment: old_df is my typo, sorry for that... have updated it

Comment: @Heng Check the answer.